# Where is the Karma configuration file located?

Tags: browser, karma

I want to change Karma browser from Chrome to Firefox? How could I do that? I am unable to locate the directory where Karma server is installed.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Karma configuration section](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/intro/configuration.html): The configuration file can be generated using karma init from a terminal, where you can set the browser.